# Html checkBox onchange not working

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, onchange

```
<input class="jProblemClass" id="Checkbox{%= ID %}" type="checkbox" onchange="problemPicker.onChangeProblemCheckBox('{%=ID %}');"/>
```

After first check or uncheck nothing happens. Afetr second click, call my function `problemPicker.onChangeProblemCheckBox`, but i get ID first check. Why? Can help me anybody?

```
onChangeProblemCheckBox: function(id) {
    if ($('#CheckBox' + id).attr("checked") == true) {
        problemPicker.addToCheckProblems(id);

        var checkboxes = $('.jProblemClass:checked');

        if ((checkboxes.length > general.limit) && (general.limit != 0)) {
            alert('The limit of ' + general.limit + ' problems exceeded. Please deselect ' + (checkboxes.length - general.limit).toString() + '.');
        }
    } else {
        problemPicker.delFromCheckProblems(id);
    }
},
```

Comment: You might want to show us what the function does - maybe the problem is there...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Bro use onclick event instead onchange..**
Reason...
According to the Javascript references I've read, onchange fires after the
focus is lost. Unless you click somewhere else, the focus is not lost in IE.
The other browsers must not be waiting for the focus to be lost before
firing onchange - which suggest they are not following the spec correctly
(despite it making more sense to fire at that point). How about using
onclick and onkeydown/onkeyup instead (by using both onclick and
onkeyup/onkeydown you cover both mouse and keyboard setting of the
checkbox).
REFERENCE : http://www.winvistatips.com/re-onchange-event-checkbox-not-working-properly-t311364.html

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem goes from here: `$('#CheckBox' + id).attr("checked") == true`. Accordingly to HTML specs, `checked` should be set to `"checked"` when this event fires. So, try using something like `$('#CheckBox' + id).attr("checked") == "checked"` or even `$('#CheckBox' + id).attr("checked")`.

As a second option, i recommend you to use pure jquery to run your routine. For example, if you have `<input type="checkbox" id="ac">` checkbox, you can use this jq code to handle your routines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        alert("Am i checked? - " + $(this).attr("checked") + "\nMy ID:" + $(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

This case is shown in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WUA98/14/).

Comment: After i change event `onchange` on `onclick` all are work. But if i use onchange nothing work.

Comment: Then it might be that onchange do not fire until onblur fires, try setting focus on another element after checking the box.

Comment: `$('#CheckBox' + id).attr("checked") == true` is the right code. `$('#CheckBox' + id).attr("checked") == "checked"` did not work for me.

Comment: basically, HTML references specify that attribute "checked" should be either set to "checked" or do not be set. but different browsers may specify their own data. so you'd better check if this attrib is present: `$('#CheckBox' + id).attr('checked') != null`. I realized this not-so-long-ago =)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `if($('#CheckBox' + id + ':checked').length > 0)` instead, that way you led jQuery figure out it the checkbox is [checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) or not.

Also if the `onChangeProblemCheckBox` uses any internal properties in `problemPicker` but does not referens them with full path, ie `problemPicker.nnnnn`it will fail as the event will fire in the context of the element, not problemPicker. It would be as if the function was called like this `$('#CheckBox' + id).onChangeProblemCheckBox()`.

Answer (score 0):

very simple : Use onClick instead and defaultChecked to fill input.

Comment: Welcome SO @marcos-baiadori :) Please elaborate your answer.